# What is $\frac{1}{2} \int {e^{\frac{t}{2}}dt}$ equal to?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Would using substitution be helpful to get rid of the exponent of the variable?
I tried substituting "$u$" in but it did not seem to help finding the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be helpful.

$$u = t/2$$
$$du = \frac{1}{2}dt \Longrightarrow dt = 2du$$

And so:

$$\int e^{t/2} dt = 2\int e^{u}du$$

Of course, the exponential function is its own derivative, and it's own integral up to an integration constant.

Answer (score 2):

Try $u=\frac{t}{2}$. Then $du = \frac{1}{2} dt$. Therefore, $$\frac{1}{2} \int e^{\frac{t}{2}} \, dt = \int e^u \, du$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\dfrac{t}{2}$. Then,
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int e^{t/2}dt=\int e^{t/2}d(t/2)=\int e^udu$$

Answer (score -1):

$\frac 1 2 \int e^\frac t 2 dt$

= 1/2[e^(t/2)/(1/2)+C]

= e^(t/2)+C/2

= e^(t/2) + C [C-Integral Constant]